# How to prevent the keyboard to appear in phonegap?

Tags: extjs, calendar, keyboard, cordova, touch

I'm developing an application with sencha touch and phonegap, and I have been created a component extending TextField class. It works this way:

1. The user taps the field
2. The application open a modal with a calendar inside it
3. The user taps the number representing the day he wants to choose
4. The modal closes and set his value on the textfield.

I wanna know if is there a way to when the user taps the TextField, the keyboard don't appear.
Thanks.

PS: Sorry my bad english, I wish you could understand  ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been solved my problem just adding readOnly: true on my textfield.
Thanks for everyone who tried to solve it.